# Cookie Encryption/Decryption

Tags: php, cookies, encryption, passwords

I have a website where the user can choose for the website to "remember me" (AKA set a cookie) and per advice on this website, I switched my password encryption in the database to php's `password_hash()` function. Now, I can't just compare any old hash to one another so I use php's `password_verify()`. Password verify requires plaintext and a password hash.

How can I store the user's password in a browser cookie without it being plaintext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing the password in the cookie itself is a really bad idea, don't do that.

At a very high level, I would:

1. Generate a token (with something like `md5`) that consists of a couple unique (yet consistent) attributes for this user
2. Store both the user ID and this token in the cookie (separated by some known delimiter)
3. When the user visits your site, you can split out the ID and the token
4. Use the ID to fetch the user record from the database, create a new token from the DB record, and compare with the cookie token

So let's walk through this briefly. Say `$hash` is the password hash stored in the database, and you also have a `$userId` and `$username` variables for this user.

I would generate a cookie that looks something like this:

```
$token = md5($userId . $username . $hash);
$cookie = $userID . "|" . $token; // 1|XXXXXXXX
```

Now when a user visits your site and you retrieve this cookie:

```
$parts = explode("|",$cookie);
$userId = $parts[0];
$token = $parts[1];
```

Now you know who the user is *claiming* to be, but you need to verify.

Fetch the user record from the database, and then regenerate the token and compare.

```
// Assuming you just ran a SELECT query, and fetched the result into `$row`
$dbToken = md5($row['userId'] . $row['username'] . $row['hash']);
if($token == $dbToken) {
    // The user is who he claims to be! Log them in
} else {
    // The cookie token didn't match our re-generated token, don't trust this cookie
}
```

Make sense? You will likely need to modify this a bit for your situation. Hopefully this helps get you going in a good direction at least.

Comment: I had such a long answer saying the same thing and then you said it better. +1 good answer.

Comment: I think that worked (as in it's setting the cookies) and my only problem is that the way I verify the cookie isn't really working. [Code](http://pastebin.com/2nGTDnF8) (See highlighted line)

Comment: @mrkirby153 Glad that the approach seems to work for your situation. As for debugging your class specifically, start by doing `print_r($_COOKIE)` to see what you actually have. Maybe the cookie array isn't quite what you expect? Maybe `verifyDatabase` isn't being called? I think you have some general PHP debugging to do in terms of how your code works, unrelated to how the cookie tokens specifically work.

Comment: @mrkirby153 Did you get it sorted out? if you are using the cookie/token approach I provided in my answer, I'd sure appreciate if you mark the answer as accepted. =)

Comment: @jszobody Yes, I did get it sorted out. The reason why it wasn't working was because I forgot to change some if statements and stuff. You're response also inspired me to make my cookies safer too. Everything seems to be working fine! (I would +1 but I don't have enough reputation :( )

Comment: @mrkirby153 you should have enough rep now. I upvoted your question.

Comment: -1 for not having a randomization token in it. You are getting session fixation with this type of roll your own authentication mechanism.

Comment: @LucasKauffman 1) This is a 'remember me' token, not an active session ID. 2) This is almost a three-year-old answer. It was the very common approach to 'remember cookies' even for major PHP frameworks at that time. If I was to answer this question today I'd recommend a completely random 'remember me' token, stored in the users DB table and as the cookie. 3) You can always add your own answer to the question and I'll upvote it. =)